# Nan values are from griddata

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Code:

```
x=xyz_camera_frame(:,1);
y=xyz_camera_frame(:,2);
z=xyz_camera_frame(:,3);
xq=linspace(min(x),max(x),100);
yq=linspace(min(y),max(y),100);
zq=griddata(x,y,z,xq,yq);
```

Issue:

Some the values returned by griddata are `Nan`. I don't understand, I using all x and y in the range of the data used to interpolate. I have the provided the data below.

Data:

```
>>xyz_camera_frame
-558.336553688600   828.056210369240    -1837.47937368187
-550.892426227711   794.936769199689    -1808.72682002260
-603.846962906934   851.372915856983    -1712.09366057117
-818.811157160022   884.767235971338    -1558.25014602362
-1012.30463037728   831.185172081933    -1427.70165589871
-1045.82571004598   692.455128071284    -1399.30798613536
-992.467127527465   608.779584169659    -1394.52549384845
-1081.69261657566   561.817230061316    -1340.99127748195
-1285.64088734587   450.170033074173    -1138.19479622127
-1285.64088734587   450.170033074173    -1138.19479622127
-1442.20131036315   339.085936148270    -925.183326861918
-1528.67244791715   159.820175944104    -804.659778016503
-1500.11791629949   -87.9237558678489   -808.071629700352
-1455.92921560688   -48.0074731557390   -860.016984208648
-1521.01192278841   -136.929311517256   -659.967982600971
-1565.91773124737   -297.661714131866   -346.577836677670
-1566.45934705874   -337.020087203977   -309.538723290191
-1745.00981140219   -235.550194307685   -455.832248827105
-1834.08270382282   644.019464202153    -1183.08785373590
-1696.77284981365   737.809996970051    -1515.67442101056
739.194190935881    1663.82013156789    -2471.68463176660
-721.669766608237   2445.65386536664    -3539.59304186409
82.8520290560576    2818.78604007141    -3389.08120001113
-629.351172568747   2128.70093285375    -3192.07545943683
-837.020672380509   1894.66259228118    -2991.05779359167
-985.624586756649   1639.63742841083    -2845.92385466952
-1804.89642560898   1549.58412361620    -2158.95908581209
-1659.24846065565   1469.47555756921    -2202.10672095917
-2201.47663125592   863.075386146258    -1513.62346475461
-2650.05442315804   460.898429832640    -774.869210275370
-2665.94697165560   566.948145814364    -684.863017871965
-1022.23879277860   2670.60414151831    -2826.15153823890
-2139.00577921475   1916.48630564150    -2128.33892716129
-580.817281550792   540.043524610704    -1821.51585236142
-1228.31732819579   1972.60682551667    -1942.10992500455
-1702.07940137072   1646.02189901725    -2083.20279568629
```

Update(@Suever's answer):

```
x=xyz_camera_frame(:,1);
y=xyz_camera_frame(:,2);
z=xyz_camera_frame(:,3);
% get the points 
inds = convhull(x, y);
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x), max(x), 100), linspace(min(y), max(y), 100));
touse = inpolygon(xq, yq, x(inds), y(inds));
xq = xq(touse);
yq = yq(touse);
zq=griddata(x,y,z,xq,yq);
```

Here zq is a 1-d vector as opposed to a matrix which gives this error later

```
K>> mesh(xq,yq,zq);
Error using mesh (line 58)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`griddata` uses the convex hull of your data as the region over which the interpolant is valid (without extrapolation). Any query points that are outside of this region will receive a `NaN` value.

So based on the example data you've provided we can compute the convex hull  (the valid interpolation region). And we can visualize it along-side the locations of your original data.

```
inds = convhull(xyz_camera_frame(:,1), xyz_camera_frame(:,2));
plot(xyz_camera_frame(inds,1), xyz_camera_frame(inds,2), 'r');
```

[image]

Any query points outside of this red region are going to give you a `NaN` value. So now let's plot the points that you're actually querying.

```
xq = linspace(min(x),max(x),100);
yq = linspace(min(y),max(y),100);

[xq, yq] = meshgrid(xq, yq);

plot(xq, yq, 'g.')
```

[image]

You'll see that many of your query points are outside of the convex hull. All of these points will be `NaN` in your result.

The only way that you won't have `NaN` values in your result, is if the convex hull bounds all of your data points (i.e. you have input data at all corners of the bounding box defined by the minimum and maximum x and y values).

**Update**

If you only want the data for points within the convex hull you really have two options.

1. Use `inpolygon` to check which points are inside of the convex hull and only use these.

   ```
   inds = convhull(x, y);

   [xq, yq] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x), max(x), 100), linspace(min(y), max(y), 100));

   touse = inpolygon(xq, yq, x(inds), y(inds));

   xq = xq(touse);
   yq = yq(touse);

   zq = griddata(x, y, z, xq, yq);
   ```
2. Just remove the NaN's after interpolation (likely faster)

   ```
   zq = griddata(x, y, z, xq, yq);

   toremove = isnan(zq);
   xq(toremove) = [];
   yq(toremove) = [];
   zq(toremove) = [];
   ```

Comment: Thanks! That explains the issue. What could be better to take points instead of linspace such that they lie in convex hull.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia How you approach that really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: How can I get a subset of the linspace points that lie in the convex hull only. This way I can skip the Nans.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia updated with an example of how to do that

Comment: Thanks, please check the update I posted in the question.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Of course it's not a matrix...we remove the NaN's.. Why not just leave the `NaN` values in there?

Comment: Not sure, what does plotting Nans do. Should I use ~isnan()?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia When plotting, `NaN` values are typically ignored. This way you can have a matrix input to `mesh` but the `NaN` values will not appear in the result.